# Why is the process of obtaining ObjectContext from dbContext so slow?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I use in my work Entity Framework Code first (6.2). One of the biggest problem with such approach is slow performance at first query. I use **InteractiveViews** nuget package to workaround this issue, but unfortunately, it doesn't give expected productivity growth.

When I was experimenting with source code, i noticed that

`**( dbContext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext**`

took i very long time ( 8 sec. in my case).

**Q:** What is the reason for the such big delay? Is it normal or it possible somehow to solve?

Comment: Calling this will cause your context to initialise, the second call should be quick.

Comment: if  I create dbContext var ctx = new DbContext() it also initialise, but takes only ~500ms. what's the difference?

Comment: No, merely creating a DbContext without making any database call will not initialize the object model.

Comment: The DBContext, from memory is a much slimmer Api.  Quite why casting takes so long is a mystery.  Try profiling thr DB at the same time.  Alternately just use the DbApi its suotable for most stuff from memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### new DbContext

Creating a new context such as `var ctx = new DbContext()` doesn't make the model to be compiled or do any database verification with the Migration History table.

It could take 500ms because it `JIT` compiles some method within Entity Framework or another third library that you may call in your constructors.

It's hard to know why it takes 500ms because they might have several reasons.

### (dbContext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext

Doing it mean the `OnModelCreating` method will be invoked, and the model will be compiled for the first time. Some query will be executed on the database as well.

The best way to find out is making a simple test, adding some break point, and enabling SQL Profiler to see it by yourself:

```
var ctx = new CurrentContext1();
var objectContext = (ctx as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
```

You will suffer from the same performance problem as people usually report when they ask [Why Entity Framework First Load is Slow](http://entityframework-faq.net/why-first-query-slow)

Comment: I noticed that  if Database.SetInitializer<dbContext>(null) EF doesn't sent any queries to database (only one - for indification of server version). But How  then it finds out about database structure??

Comment: The structure is built via the EDMX file (database first) or your model (code first), your database doesn't really matter here. SQL Executed is normally to ensure the database has not been changed. I believe you can find a better/improved answer than this one but that's around how it works.

Comment: Thank for your help~